# Making 2 columns instead of 2 rows per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey I've got this table I made..

```
 Pat_Name        Case_Num         Doc_Entry_Date            Doc_id          Doc_Name          Doc_Order_By_Case            
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Jane            0943085          2022-07-09 10:00          3421             Said             1
 Jane            0943085          2022-07-09 11:00          8998             Juan             2
 Jane            0943085          2022-07-09 12:00          2429             Danielle         3
 Ben             0945666          2022-07-10 09:34          8998             Juan             1
 Ben             0945666          2022-07-10 09:38          7651             Ari              2
 Harry           0945331          2022-07-10 10:00          3421             Said             1
 Harry           0945331          2022-07-10 11:00          7651             Ari              2
 Hili            0945488          2022-07-10 18:00          6566             Vera             1
 Karen           0945112          2022-07-11 01:00          6566             Vera             1
```

What I want is one line per Case_Num with the first Doc column and another column for the second Doc (according to the time)

I've done the Doc_Order_By_Case column to make it easier with:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Case_Num ORDER BY Doc_Entry_Date) AS Doc_Order_By_Case
```

Cases with more then 3 Docs I dont care about the third one.. only the first 2 Docs

Cases with 1 Doc I want the column of second Doc to be NULL

```
 Pat_Name    Case_Num     First_Doc_Entry_Date      First_Doc_Id    First_Doc_Name   Second_Doc_Entry_Date    Second_Doc_Id     Second_Doc_Name
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Jane        0943085      2022-07-09 10:00          3421            Said             2022-07-09 11:00         8998               Juan
 Ben         0945666      2022-07-10 09:34          8998            Juan             2022-07-10 09:38         7651               Ari
 Harry       0945331      2022-07-10 10:00          3421            Said             2022-07-10 11:00         7651               Ari 
 Hili        0945488      2022-07-10 18:00          6566            Vera              NULL                    NULL               NULL
 Karen       0945112      2022-07-11 01:00          6566            Vera              NULL                    NULL               NULL
```

Can you help me with code for it??? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Hi KapSht . You'he already done. Just filter out by `Doc_Order_By_Case=1` while keeping the current SELECT statement within a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on 2 ways.

1. Pivot up the data - group by `Pat_name, case_num` and aggregate the values wherever the `Doc_Order_By_Case` column is 1/2 separately

Code:

```
select Pat_Name,case_num,
max(case when Doc_Order_By_Case = 1 then Doc_Entry_Date else null end ) as First_Doc_Entry_Date,
max(case when Doc_Order_By_Case = 1 then Doc_id else null end ) as First_Doc_Id,
max(case when Doc_Order_By_Case = 1 then Doc_Name else null end ) as First_Doc_Name,

max(case when Doc_Order_By_Case = 2 then Doc_Entry_Date else null end ) as Second_Doc_Entry_Date,
max(case when Doc_Order_By_Case = 2 then Doc_id else null end ) as Second_Doc_Id,
max(case when Doc_Order_By_Case = 2 then Doc_Name else null end ) as Second_Doc_Name 
from Table1 group by Pat_Name,case_num
```

2. Select all records where `Doc_Order_By_Case` flag is `1` and join it with records where `Doc_Order_By_Case` is `2`

Code:

```
select 
  a.pat_name, 
  a.case_num, 
  a.Doc_Entry_Date as First_Doc_Entry_Date, 
  a.Doc_id as First_Doc_Id, 
  a.Doc_Name as First_Doc_Name, 
  b.Doc_Entry_Date as Second_Doc_Entry_Date, 
  b.Doc_id as Second_Doc_Id, 
  b.Doc_Name as Second_Doc_Name 
from 
  (
    select Pat_Name, case_num, Doc_Entry_Date, Doc_id, Doc_Name 
    from Table1 
    where Doc_Order_By_Case = 1
  ) a 
  left join (
    select Pat_Name, case_num, Doc_Entry_Date, Doc_id, Doc_Name 
    from Table1 
    where Doc_Order_By_Case = 2
  ) b on a.case_num = b.case_num
```

**Output:**
[image]

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d9d85/12)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with LimitedRecords as (
    select *
    from (
             select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Case_Num ORDER BY Doc_Entry_Date) AS Doc_Order_By_Case
             from @DATA
         ) AGG
    where Doc_Order_By_Case <= 2
)
select 
       L1.Doc_Order_By_Case, L2.Doc_Order_By_Case, L1.Pat_Name, L1.Case_Num,
       L1.Doc_Entry_Date as First_Doc_Entry_Date, L1.Doc_Id as First_Doc_Id, L1.Doc_Name as First_Doc_Name,
       L2.Doc_Entry_Date as Second_Doc_Entry_Date, L2.Doc_Id as Second_Doc_Id, L2.Doc_Name as Second_Doc_Name
from LimitedRecords L1 left join LimitedRecords L2 on L1.Pat_Name = L2.Pat_Name and L1.Doc_Order_By_Case < L2.Doc_Order_By_Case
where L1.Doc_Order_By_Case = 1
```